# Can I make a smear frame from the blender?

Tags: animation, modifiers, transforms

https://hocuspocus-studio.fr/tools/product/overmorpher-world-space/

The link above is a plug-in of 3dsmax.
I'm an animator. That's why I need a smear frame

I'm about to change my main tool with a blender.
But if it's not possible smear frame, I can't get out of max.

Please help me.

[image]

Comment: could you please tell a bit about what is a smear frame? If it's mesh deformation, perhaps shapekeys are what you want? or lattice or mesh deform?

Comment: http://www.maxidiazblog.com/en/tecnicas-de-animacion-cartoon/ 1

like this! It’s kind of a motionblur.

Comment: oh ok it's like a deformation of the mesh between its shape at frame 1 and its shape at frame 3, shapekeys would be a bit tedious

Comment: But there's no other way than Shapekey, is there?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: perhaps someone knows, I've edited your question and added a picture from your link

Comment: oh! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

If all the animation is done using the grease pencil, it is quite simple. Enter sculpt mode and you can use any of the brushes to smear the drawing at will.

[image]

Comment: Wow! cool! Thank you for attaching the reference image.
It helped me a lot.

Can it be applied to 3d?

Comment: Yes. Using shape keys.