# How to make texture smear? (using textures for eyes)

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

Hi i'm trying to make eyes that act like hand drawn ones but i'm unsure of how that kind of stuff can be made.

I'm trying to make a character with a TV for a head so the head will be 3d but the face will be 2d
(also i'm trying to find a way to pixelate the animations for the eyes)

I've thought about using grease pencil but i'm unsure of how to turn that into a texture or stick on the face

I'm trying to go for an effect like this (except just the eyes the rest is 3d):
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144286/can-i-make-a-smear-frame-from-the-blender/144337#144337

Comment: yes but that's purely in grease pencil, i wanna make only the eyes 2d